# What does the exception "Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040653" when calling IFeatureClass.Search in ArcObjects mean?

Tags: .net, esri, arcobjects

I'm supporting an application built on ESRI ArcObjects where the original developers are long since gone. The application after having worked fine for a couple of years has started failing with this exception. The application runs on a daily schedule.

The error message isn't very helpful. Any ideas what the cause of the error might be?

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040653
Date: Thursday, 4 March 2010
Time: 1:47:33 a.m.
Stack trace:    
   at ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureClass.Search(IQueryFilter filter, Boolean Recycling)
```

Comment: Any recent changes to the system? If not, googling that error code turns up at least one useful thread.

Comment: Yeah the last post on this thread (http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1147&t=191348) pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the error was caused by the **IQueryFilter.WhereClause** property that was getting passed into the Search method, contained the name of a field that didn't exist in the feature class.

It would be nice if the exception thrown had a relevant message. It would've saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link to an article on 
[ESRI error codes](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/dotnet/a3bd05c8-64a6-4dd4-acb3-0d10b021f2f8.htm) that can be used to look up an error.

The particualar error you recieved is defined as FDO_E_FIELD_NOT_FOUND, which you already figured out indicates the attempted use of a field name that is not in the table.